# Open the log file in the local drive onclick of HTML button using VB script

Tags: html, vbscript

I want to open a log file **(test.log)** present in my local machine in the **(C: drive** location **)** using VB script function say **"LogGen"**. This log file should open onClick of the HTML button named **Log** as in below code, upon clicking the button, the VB script function"LogGen" should be called and executed.

```
<input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="  Login  " onclick="LogGen">
```

I am new to VB scripts. Can someone suggest me some sample code for the Vb script function to fetch the log file present in the local directory?

---

**NEW PROBLEM CODE**

---

```
Sub LogOpen()
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
Dim fso, MyFile, FileName, TextLine
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Open the file for output.
FileName = "c:\\testfile.txt"
  Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForWriting, True, TristateTrue)
' Open the file for input.
 Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
' Read from the file and display the results.
 Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
     TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
     Document.Write TextLine & "<br />"
 Loop
'MyFile.Close
End Sub
```

I did the one as shown above and called this subroutine in a button event called "Log" but it doesn't work. **A blank screen with yz typed on it appears** and it occupies the entire window and then application has to be closed. **Can you please suggest where is the mistake.** I want the logfile in C directory to pop out on click of the Log button but this is not happening.

```
<input type="button" name="Log" value="Log" onclick="LogOpen"><br/>
```

Comment: what's this gotta do with javascript? i said hey hey you you, get off of my cloud.

Comment: oh yeah rightly pointed I removed the javascript tag... :) do you have any idea about vbscript by the way as i am looking for some hints to my query..Badly trapped

Comment: i do; search for snippets or a small library demonstrating use of the FileSystemObject interface to load local files. for long logs, use ReadLine to avoid filling RAM with the entire log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this code to give you some idea about what do you want to do :

```
<html>
<Title>How to open and read the log file with HTA</Title>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
ICON="cmd.exe"
APPLICATIONNAME = "How to open and read the log file with HTA" 
BORDER="dialog"
BORDERSTYLE="complex"
WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
>
<style>
body{
background-color: Black;
}
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/Vbscript">
Option Explicit
Dim File
File = "C:\MyLogFile.txt"
'***********************************************************
Sub LoadMyFile()
    myDiv.innerHTML = LoadFile(File)
End Sub
'***********************************************************
Function LoadFile(File)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fso,F,ReadMe,Tab,i,paragraphe
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    LoadFile = Err.Number
    If Err.Number <> 0  Then
        MsgBox Err.Description,16," Error"
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReadMe = F.ReadAll
    Tab = split(ReadMe,vbcrlf)
    For i = lbound(Tab) to ubound(Tab)
        paragraphe=paragraphe & Tab(i) & "<br>"
    Next
    LoadFile = paragraphe
End Function
'***********************************************************
Sub Clear()
    myDiv.innerHTML = ""
End Sub
'***********************************************************
Function LogOpen()
    Dim Ws,iReturn,strError
    Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On Error Resume Next
    iReturn = Ws.Run(File,1,False)
    If Err.Number <> 0  Then
        strError = "<b><font color=Red>The file "& File &" dosen't exists !</font></b>"
        myDiv.InnerHTML = strError
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
'***********************************************************
</script>
<body text="white">
<center><input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="  Load LogFile  " onclick="LoadMyFile()">
<input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="  Open LogFile  " onclick="LogOpen()">
<input type="button" value="  Clear  " onclick="Clear()"></center>
<Div id="myDiv"></Div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hackoo, Thanks!!very nice one ...It worked , I have one query, can I also access the remote machine files here by doing something like this : file:///C:\MyLogFile.txt ? I am able to get the remote machine session handled in my code using this Set oWMIService = oWbemLocator.ConnectServer(host, "root\cimv2", user,password). Kindly suggest, your codes work real nice for local files will it work fine if I do the changes in the path as I have mentioned in my first line?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
Const ForReading = 1
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objTextFile = fs.OpenTextFile(filePathto/test.log, ForReading)
```

There's a more complete description here: [vbs open file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: In my original thread I have posted my new code which is causing problem. I have posted the issue I am getting in it, could you please suggest where am I going wrong ?